# How was Peter Parker able to use EDITH in the end?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

Now, I could easily be missing a detail here, but my understanding is that the following steps occurred (obvious spoilers):

1. Peter gets EDITH and "registers" himself using the glasses.
2. Peter 'befriends' Beck and determines he's better suited to use EDITH. *Peter transfers full control of EDITH to Beck*.
3. Betrayal and shenanigans from Beck/Mysterio ensues, ending with Beck's death.
4. Peter takes back control of EDITH *somehow* (and without any indication of a transfer of control?) and orders them to abort.

How was #4 possible given the fact that Peter gave up control? I wouldn't have assumed they could both have control, since Peter never attempts to give EDITH commands during the time Beck is using it, unless Peter (in)conveniently forgot/didn't know up until the very end. The best guess I have is that control fell back to Peter after Beck's death somehow, but I have no proof.

I've seen a couple of posts on other sites, but they all seem like conjecture and speculation. Nothing official.

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/101957/why-was-this-needed-earlier-but-not-later

Comment: @Raj - I must be blind because that's pretty much what I was looking for. Assuming their vague wording is why it didn't crop up in my Google searches... It's still more speculative-y than I'd prefer, but perhaps the best we have right now.

Comment: The reason Peter couldn't issue orders to EDITH until he had taken the glasses back is presumably simply that he needed to be wearing the glasses.  Do we see anyone give EDITH orders without them?

Comment: “Peter never attempts to give EDITH commands during the time Beck is using it” — yup. As @HarryJohnston alludes to, EDITH seems to verify Peter earlier in the movie by doing some sort of scan of his face. Presumably the authentication that enables Peter to take control of the glasses requires him to be wearing them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can’t offer anything official on this, as far as I know there isn’t anything yet, but speculation offers up the most probable explanation.

Whilst Peter does “transfer” ownership to Beck EDITH only adds Beck as a user and doesn’t remove Peter from the system. This can be reasoned as Tony himself had to add Peter and presumably kept ownership himself in case he did survive the Time Heist and Battle for Earth saving an awkward conversation where he gives Peter the glasses then asks him to transfer ownership back.

As for why it didn’t transfer full ownership but rather only added Beck it seems to be a fail safe option. I bet Tony wouldn’t want anyone else to be able to take EDITH and lock him out of the system. So he probably did the same thing for Peter considering the glasses were only given to him upon his death.

It’s worth noting that Peter is able to use EDITH ***before*** Beck dies so that rules out one of your possible theories.

Comment: Until/unless something official comes along, this makes the most sense to me. I suppose it's just like adding another user account to a computer; the other user is not deleted in the process. And good point with Peter using it before Beck died - I knew I wouldn't get the details 100% right :)

Comment: Also, it's probable that Beck isn't dead.   Because superheros and $$$.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Sure we never see him dead only dying and with the illusion tech anything is possible. I think barring any other evidence though at the moment we have to assume he is dead.

Comment: Beck isn't dead for sure, he might appear in coming disney+ series